# How to compare and summarize continues and factorial designed experiments?

Tags: estimation, regression-coefficients, meta-analysis, meta-regression

I am new here so I hope this question is expressed properely. I would like to compare a summary of factorial ordinal experiments with e.g., 4 concentrations to studies using a continues vector IV. To do so, on could log the DV $log(y)$ as well as the IV ($log(x)$), as such $log(E(y|x))=\beta\cdot\log(x)$ (or log as link function ) then, $\beta_i$ can be coaresly treated as elasticity coefficient and normally distributed RV. One could ignore the factorial design of the experiment and treat the factors as observations from a continues vector and fit a model. Somehow this feel intuitively wrong to ignore the factorial design, but I cannot explain why, any thoughts?

So not to ignore the ordered experimental ordered design I could assume that 4 concentrations are $x=0.1, 1, 10, 100$ are analysed factorial, then the expected relation amount ordered factors treated as a “latent” construct. Hereby, I try to express the “latent” construct as the change of difference in $mean = dΔ_{i, i+1}=\beta_i-\beta_i+1$ over the ordinal categories. Thus, I get 3 (or $n-1$) comparisons (ordered difference in means) $dΔ_{1,2}=\beta_1-\beta_2$, $dΔ_{2,3}=\beta_2-\beta_3$ and $d_{3,4}=\beta_3-\beta_4$. For each comparison $dΔ_i, i+1$ with its accompanying SE. Their expected "latent" mean changes $E(dΔ)=\frac{dΔ_{i, i+n}}{(n-k-1)}$ and $se = \frac{\sqrt{{SE(\Delta_{i,i+1})}^2 \cdot (n-2)}}{n-k-2} $. Then $\bar{x} = \frac{\sum(\log(x_i))}{n} $ and $E(y|\bar{x})=dΔ * \bar{x}$ = $log(E(y|\bar{x}))=\beta\cdot\log(\bar{x})$ Then one could answer the question if $\beta$ = 0.2 then a 20% (±se) change in $y$ is the expectation when $\bar{x}$. This seem to  make it till some extend comparable summary between factorial an continues designs.

I feel uncomfortable with this approach but would like to use or coarsely compare a summary of factorial with continues design, not treating them as “exact”. I preferably do not want to standardize as this removes information on the unites of change. Any kind and thorough thoughts and response are appreciated. And, perhaps a much simpler solution exists?